# Processing - Line Implementation Help

Tags: java, math, line, processing

I jumped into Processing (the language) today. I've been trying to implement a line without the line() function. In other words, I'm trying to replicate the line() function with my own code. I'm almost there, but not. (There's a screen, and you can click around, and this function connects those clicks with lines.)

There are four different line slopes I'm dealing with (m>1, 0

**If you could just glance at the following code, and tell me where I've gone wrong, I'd be grateful.**

```
int xStart = -1;                // Starting x and y are negative. 
int yStart = -1;                // No lines are drawn when mouseReleased() and x/y are negative.
boolean isReset = false;        // Turns true when 'r' is pressed to reset polygon chain.
int clickCounter = 0;            // Changes background color every 10 clicks (after c is pressed).
color backgroundColor = 0;          // Starting background color. Changed occasionally.
color lineColor = 255;
int weight = 1;

void setup() {
  size(800, 800);            // Initial size is 800x800
  background(backgroundColor);            // ...background is black.
  smooth();                
  stroke(lineColor);               //... lines/points are white.
  strokeWeight(weight);
}

void draw() {
}

void mousePressed(){
  clickCounter++;
}

void mouseReleased(){                // mouseReleased used instead of mousePressed to avoid dragged clicks.
  point(mouseX, mouseY);             // Draws white point at clicked coordinates.
  if((xStart < 0 && yStart < 0) || isReset){      // If x/y negative or if r was pressed, set start points and return. No line drawn.
    xStart = mouseX;
    yStart = mouseY;
    isReset = false;              // Reset isReset to false. 
    return;
  }  
                                                        // Sends starting and ending points to createLine function. 
  createLine(xStart, yStart, mouseX, mouseY);           // createLine(...) - Creates line from start point to end point.  
  xStart = mouseX;                                        // Start point = last click location. End point = Current click location.
  yStart = mouseY;                                   // Sets starting coordinates for next click at current click point.
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'x')                  // EXTRA CREDIT ADDITION: If x is pressed -> Exit program.
    exit();
  else if(key == 'c'){            // EXTRA CREDIT ADDITTION: If c pressed -> Set background black to clear all lines/points on screen.
    if(clickCounter > 10){
       backgroundColor = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));        // EXTRA CREDIT ADDITION: If cleared and clickCounter is greater 
       clickCounter = 0;                                                        // ...than 10, background changes to random color.
    }
    background(backgroundColor);
    xStart = -1;                // Must set points negative so line is not drawn after next new point is made (since there will only be one point on the screen).
    yStart = -1;
  }
  else if(key == 'r'){          // If r pressed -> Reset: Next click will create new point that isn't connected with line to current points.
    isReset = true;
    lineColor = color(random(255), random(255), random(255));    // EXTRA CREDIT ADDITION: When dot chain is "reset", line changes color.
    weight = (int)random(10);
    strokeWeight(weight);                                    // EXTRA CREDIT ADDITION: ...and line/dot thickness changes.
    stroke(lineColor);
  }                                                                
  else
    return;  
}

// createLine(): Function which draws line from (x0,y0) to (x1,y1).
void createLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1){
  // 1) Line function draws from left to right. (Does not work right to left.) Check and swap points if ending point is left of starting point.
  if(x1 < x0){
    print("LEFT TO RIGHT SWITCH. \n");
    createLine(x1, y1, x0, y0);      // Drawing the line left to right cuts the number of line types we have to deal with to 4 regions.
    return;                              // Regions: slope > 1; 0 < slope < 1; -1 < slope < 0; slope < -1.
  }
  // Declare/Initialize data needed to draw line with midpoint algorithm.
  int dx = x1 - x0;
  int dy = y1 - y0;            //dy = Negative when y0 is lower on screen than y2, because origin is top left.
  print(y0 + "  " + x0 + "  " +y1 + "  " + x1+ "  x    y  \n");
  print(dy + "  " + dx + "  dx    dy\n");
  // Handle vertical & horizontal lines...
  if(dx == 0 || dy == 0){              // If slope is vertical or horizontal, create line with simple function. 
      while(y1 != y0){                    // If vertical -> Paint by incrementing/decrementing y until points connect.
        if(y1 > y0){                          // If new point is above -> Draw upwards.
          y0 = y0 + 1;                
          point(x0, y0);
        }
        else{                                // It new point below -> Draw downwards.
          y0 = y0 - 1;
          point(x0, y0);
        }
      }
      while(x1 != x0){                    // If horizontal -> Paint by incrementing x until points connect (will be left to right line always).
          x0 = x0 + 1;                
          point(x0, y0);
      }
      return;
    }
  // Handle slanted lines...
  double tempDX = x1 - x0;
  double tempDY = y1 - y0;            // Had to create dx and dy as doubles because typecasting dy/dx to a double data type wasn't working.
  double m = (-tempDY / tempDX);      // m = line slope. (Note - The dy value is negative because positive y is downwards on the screen.)
  print("SLOPE CALCULATED: " + m + "\n");
  int deltaN = (2 * -dx);        // deltaX is the amount to increment d after choosing the next pixel on the line.
  int deltaNE = (2 * (-dy - dx));      // ...where X is the direction moved for that next pixel. 
  int deltaE = (2 * -dy);            // deltaX variables are used below to plot line.
  int deltaSE = (2 * (dy + dx));
  int deltaS = (2 * dx);
  int x = x0; 
  int y = y0;
  int d = 0;                            // d = Amount d-value changes from pixel to pixel. Depends on slope.
  int region = 0;                  // region = Variable to store slope region. Different regions require different formulas.
 if(m > 1){                            // if-statement: Initializes d, depending on the slope of the line.
      d = -dy - (2 * dx);                  // If slope is 1-Infiniti. -> Use NE/N initialization for d.
      region = 1;
  }
  else if(m == 1)
    region = 2;
  else if(m > 0 && m < 1){
      d = (2 * -dy) - dx;                  // If slope is 0-1 -> Use NE/E initialization for d.
      region = 3;
  }
  else if(m < 0 && m > -1){          
      d = (2 * dy) + dx;                  // If slope is 0-(-1) -> Use E/SE initliazation for d.
      region = 4;
  }
  else if(m == -1)
    region = 5;
  else if(m < -1){
      d = dy + (2 * dx);                  // If slope is (-1)-(-Infiniti) -> Use SE/S initialization for d.
      region = 6;
  }
  while(x < x1){                    // Until points are connected...
        if(region == 1){          // If in region one...
              if(d <= 0){                // and d<=0...
              d += deltaNE;            // Add deltaNE to d, and increment x and y.
              x = x + 1; 
              y = y - 1;
            }
            else{              
              d += deltaN;        // If d > 0 -> Add deltaN, and increment y.
              y = y - 1;
            }
        }
        else if(region == 2){
             x = x + 1;
             y = y - 1; 
        }
        else if(region == 3){     
                if(d <= 0){              
              d += deltaE;
              x = x + 1; 
            }
            else{
              d += deltaNE;
              x = x + 1;
              y = y - 1;
            }
        }
        else if(region == 4){    
              if(d <= 0){              
              d += deltaSE;
              x = x + 1; 
              y = y + 1;
            }
            else{
              d += deltaE;
              x = x + 1;
            }
        }
        else if(region == 5){
             x = x + 1;
             y = y + 1; 
        }
        else if(region == 6){        
              if(d <= 0){              
              d += deltaSE;
              x = x + 1; 
              y = y + 1;
            }
            else{
              d += deltaS;
              y = y + 1;
            }
          }
        point(x, y);          
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Post less code and describe the error.  This isn't a code review service.  The more precise you can be in describing your problem, the better your chances are of getting an answer you can act on.

Answer (score 0):

When programs pause, look for while() loops that don't resolve properly. I inserted the following println statements into your while loop to print out what was happening. Then I recreated the problematic condition and quit the program, and checked the console for signs of what was going wrong.

```
println("top of the while loop to ya...");
println("x: " + x + ", x1: " + x1);
println("region: " + region + ", d: " + d);
```

It looks like region 6 is causing the pausing problem. If d > 0, it is never decreased and x is never increased, so there is no way to satisfy the while condition.

With the same set of statements you can troubleshoot the inaccurate line issue. It occurs in region 4, but I'll leave the details as an exercise.